# Разница между генератором и list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть два простых выражения

```py
a  = [x for x in range(10)]
print(a)
>> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
b  = (x for x in range(10))
>> <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fa7a710cc50>
```

Объясните почему так происходит.

Comment: В первом случае вы квадратными скобками указали, что вам нужен список - получили список. Во втором случае круглыми скобками показали, что вам нужен генератор - получили генератор. Что запросили, то и получили. В чем вопрос?

Comment: Между генераторами разницы нет. В первом случае вы запросили содержание каждой страницы из книги, во втором номер полки и зал, где эта книга лежит.

Comment: В первом случае не генератор, а `list comprehension`.

Comment: по идее в обоих случаях создается последовательность, в первом случае возвращается список, во втором - объект. Вопрос разницы между самими конструкциями.
К примеру к у объекта "b" есть метод __next__() в тот момент как генератор "a" возвращает просто список

Answer (score 12):

Разница в том, что в первом случае вы создаете **список**, используя генераторное выражение, с этим списком можно работать так же как и с обычным, ничего необычного. Во втором же случае вы создаете **генератор**, это тоже итерируемый объект, но прочесть его можно всего один раз, это связано с тем, что они не хранят значения в памяти, а генерируют их на лету. Соответственно в переменной `b` у вас хранится не список, а объект-генератор. С точки зрения затрат памяти, где это возможно, лучше использовать генератор

Пример того, что генератор становится недоступным после одного использования:

```
b = (x for x in range(10))

print(*b)      # 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
print('___')   # ___
print(*b)      # Не печатает ничего
```