# Генератор и список в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Почему не работает генератор при таком написании кода

```py
print('\n', i for i in range(n), '\n', a for a in cv, '\n', sep='')
```

выдаёт

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "L:\Програмирование\Python_school\grafi\cvetnoj dozhdj\main.py", line 20
    print('\n', i for i in range(n), '\n', a for a in cv, '\n', sep='')
               ^
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized
```

но зато работает при

```py
print('\n', [i for i in range(n)], '\n', [a for a in cv], '\n', sep='')
```

но тогда выдаёт

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]
```

Что делать если мне нужно что-бы код выдал

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6
1 1 1 1 1 3 3
```

Кто сможет помочь?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Синтаксическая ошибка из-за того, что генератор не обрамлен скобками. Чтобы вывести все элементы списка или генератора, а не сам список, можно использовать оператор `*`, который распаковывает его.

```
n = 7
cv = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]

print('\n', *(i for i in range(n)), '\n', *(a for a in cv), '\n', sep=' ')
```

вывод:

```
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 
 1 1 1 1 1 3 3
```

Comment: Поясните пожалуйста, что означает ```*``` в данном контексте. Это просто синтаксический сахар для вывода переменной из списка? 

Возможно ли вывести таким же образом список, но без пробелов между цифрами? Что бы получился следующий результат:
```0123456 1111133```

Comment: @gohxr дополнил ответ. Можно и без пробелов, просто в `sep` заносим нужное значение-разделитель

Comment: "Что такое *args и **kwargs в Python?" - https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/482464/ - свежак прямо в тему

Comment: спасибо за ответ

Comment: @whizz169 есть разница в каких скобках писать генератор?

Comment: @Shush1k всмысле?

Comment: @finally ну он написал так: `print('\n', *(i for i in range(n)), '\n', *(a for a in cv), '\n', sep=' ')` А я хочу понять, в чем отличие от этого: `print('\n', *[i for i in range(n)], '\n', *[a for a in cv], '\n', sep=' ')`

Comment: @Shush1k В квадратных скобках получается в результате готовый сгенерированный список, а в круглых - собственно генератор (без готового результата). В данном случае разницы нет, поскольку берутся все элементы последовательности разом, но если использовать результат потом как-то по-другому, то разница в принципе может быть и по количеству используемой памяти и по каким-то ещё деталям.

Comment: @Shush1k вот в этом вопросе я объяснял разницу между генераторами, посмотрите https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1050376/Обьясните-разницу-между-генераторами/1050386#1050386

Comment: `print('\n', *range(n), '\n', *cv, '\n', sep=' ')`